# kendo proggressbar required script files

Tags: jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-progressbar

as mentioned in kendo references

> http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/what-you-need#individual-scripts

we can add specific script files for a component . so i want to do this because `kendo.all.min.js` is a big file and i don't need other stuff . and they don't mentioned progress bar files.

i tried adding:

```
/kendo/kendo.progressbar.min.js
```

but seems like it is not enough.

anyone knows about its required script files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need jquery and kendo.core:

```
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.progressbar.min.js"></script>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/scripts-interactivity